# How to test an expected formatted error in idiomatic Go?

Tags: go, testing, error-handling

This question is NOT about validation. It is just an example, but could be any other thing with formatted errors.

Let's say I have a very simple `Validate()` method that validates an extension eg. `.vcf` from a filename and I want an error saying valid extension and current extension if they don't match. Ideally, this method would be extended to do other validations and return other validation errors.

Something like:

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

type ValidationError struct {
    Msg string
}

func (v ValidationError) Error() string {
    return v.Msg
}

func Validate(fileName string) error {
    // first validation
    wantExtension := ".vcf"
    gotExtension := filepath.Ext(fileName)
    if gotExtension != wantExtension {
        return ValidationError{Msg: fmt.Sprintf("Extension %q not accepted, please use a %s file.", gotExtension, wantExtension)}
    }
    // potentially other validations
    return nil
}

func main() {
    fileName := os.Args[1]
    Validate(fileName)
}
```

I want to test it in a way that I check not only the error type (in this case error, but also the message). Something like:

```
// main_test.go
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "testing"
)

func TestValidate(t *testing.T) {
    testCases := []struct {
        name        string
        fileName    string
        expectedErr error
    }{
        {
            name:     "happy-path",
            fileName: "file.vcf",
        },
        {
            name:        "wrong-extension",
            fileName:    "file.md",
            expectedErr: ValidationError{Msg: "Extension .md not accepted, please use a .vcf file."},
        },
    }
    for _, tc := range testCases {
        t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            err := Validate(tc.fileName)
            if !errors.Is(err, tc.expectedErr) {
                t.Errorf("want (%v) got (%v)", tc.expectedErr, err)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This test will get:

```
--- FAIL: TestValidate (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestValidate/wrong-extension (0.00s)
        main_test.go:28: want (Extension .md not accepted, please use a .vcf file.) got (Extension ".md" not accepted, please use a .vcf file.)
```

I does not work since `errors.Is()` expects same memory object. Also if I use `errors.As()` the test will pass but it will not really check if the message is correct.

I also tried defining a function to return an error with the message as parameter or simpler `errors.New()` instead of custom error, but I run into the same problem that the object in memory is different in the test side, also don't know which of the three approaches would be considered more idiomatic.

How would you implement that?

UPDATE: I updated the question code to use custom error instead of `errors.New` as it is probably more fit to the case as in the answer by @kingkupps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no problem in using `errors.Is`. The code did not fail at using it.

It is the test code that is not setup correctly.

In the program, the error message is defined as `Extension ".md" not accepted, please use a .vcf file.`, like in, `return ValidationError{Msg: fmt.Sprintf("Extension %q not accepted, please use a %s file.", gotExtension, wantExtension)}`

In the test, the error message is defined as `expectedErr: ValidationError{Msg: "Extension .md not accepted, please use a .vcf file."},`

Hence, when trying to compare the two error values, the state is similar to

```
    fmt.Println(
        errors.Is(
            ValidationError{Msg: `Extension ".md" not accepted, please use a .vcf file.`},
            ValidationError{Msg: `Extension .md not accepted, please use a .vcf file.`},
        ),
    )
```

Which is expected to return false using that api as it performs equality check of comparable values.

https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.6:src/errors/wrap.go;l=46

For, reference, it is roughly equivalent to

```
    fmt.Println(
        ValidationError{Msg: `Extension ".md" not accepted, please use a .vcf file.`} ==
            ValidationError{Msg: `Extension .md not accepted, please use a .vcf file.`},
    )
```

https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comparison_operators

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-blank fields are equal.

Most certainly using errors, this one should be mentioned too

> Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value nil.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend defining your own type and having that type implement the `Error` interface. In your tests you can use `errors.As` to determine whether the returned error is an instance of the new type or is an error wrapping an instance of the new type.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
)

type ValidationError struct {
    WantExtension string
    GotExtension  string
}

func (v ValidationError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("extension %q not accepted, please use a %s file.", v.GotExtension, v.WantExtension)
}

func Validate(fileName string) error {
    fileExtension := filepath.Ext(fileName)
    if fileExtension != ".vcf" {
        return ValidationError{WantExtension: ".vcf", GotExtension: fileExtension}
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    fileName := "something.jpg"

    err := Validate(fileName)
    var vErr ValidationError
    if errors.As(err, &vErr) {
        // you can now use vErr.WantExtension and vErr.GotExtension
        fmt.Println(vErr)
        fmt.Println(vErr.WantExtension)
        fmt.Println(vErr.GotExtension)
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
extension ".jpg" not accepted, please use a .vcf file.
.vcf
.jpg
```

Then in your test, you can compare errors based on either the result of `Error()` or their fields:

```
func TestValidate(t *testing.T) {
    testCases := []struct {
        name        string
        fileName    string
        expectedErr error
    }{
        {
            name:     "happy-path",
            fileName: "file.vcf",
        },
        {
            name:        "wrong-extension",
            fileName:    "file.md",
            expectedErr: ValidationError{WantExtension: ".vcf", GotExtension: ".md"},
        },
    }
    for _, tc := range testCases {
        t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            err := Validate(tc.fileName)
            if err != nil {
                if tc.expectedErr == nil {
                    t.Errorf("unexpected error: %v", err)
                    return
                }
                
                var want ValidationError
                var got ValidationError
                if w, g := errors.As(tc.expectedErr, &want), errors.As(err, &got); w == g && w {
                    // Both errors are ValidationErrors
                    assertValidationErrorsEqual(t, want, got)
                } else if w != g {
                    // The expected and actual error differ in type
                    t.Errorf("wanted error of type %T, got error of type %T", tc.expectedErr, err)
                } else {
                    // Neither error is a ValidationError so we just assert that they produce the same error message
                    assertErrorMessagesEqual(t, tc.expectedErr, err)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

func assertErrorMessagesEqual(t *testing.T, want error, got error) {
    if w, g := want.Error(), got.Error(); w != g {
        t.Errorf("want %q, got %q", w, g)
    }
}

func assertValidationErrorsEqual(t *testing.T, want ValidationError, got ValidationError) {
    if want.WantExtension != got.WantExtension || want.GotExtension != got.GotExtension {
        t.Errorf("want %v, got %v", want, got)
    }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to @Daniel Farrell for the suggestion on using `errors.As` over a type assertion. Using `errors.As` will do what you want even if the returned error wraps an instance of `ValidationError` whereas a type assertion will not.

EDIT: Added what the test might look like in using the suggested approach.

Comment: This is a good start at an answer, but because of  wrapped errors, it's better to use `errors.As` instead of a type assertion on the top level error.  https://go.dev/play/p/Cq5MOdfHcg8

Comment: Thanks! Just updated the answer to use `errors.As` instead of a plain type assertion.

Comment: @kingkupps thanks for the answer but I got a bit confused since I told in my question `errors.As` passes but I don't know how to make use of it on test code to verify the message. Could you split the code and test code in your answer as I did in my question testing success / failure of validation?

Comment: Just added an example of how you might use this approach in your test

Comment: Thanks @kingkupps, it works! Just a suggestion for your answer as `ValidationError` can be about other validations, instead of having `WantExtension` and `GotExtension` I would create it with just a `Msg` string and receive a formatted message from the code that creates it. It also simplifies the testing code so you don't need two methods `assertErrorMessagesEqual` and `assertValidationErrorsEqual`. I will update my question to make it more clear also.